# Help identifying surface mounted component

Tags: identification, surface-mount, component-values, smartphones

While replacing the damaged screen on my wife’s Pixel 3a, I damaged one of the blue components below the FPC connector that connects the LCD assembly to the main board.

Can someone tell me what these most likely are? From the white dot, I'm assuming something with polarity?

[image]

Comment: Does it work? need a better photo

Comment: Capacitor. How is it damaged?

Comment: It would be a guess. Have you tried using a meter on one of the adjacent parts?

Comment: Maybe capacitors - use meter cap range to test. Less likely but possibly resistors. Possibly but not certainly the same values as the others in the set.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the low resolution photo. The entire area pictured is just a hair over 1 cm wide. It's hard to see but the bottom-left edge is chipped off.